# I am trying to create a bar graph and the code is not working

Tags: python, dataset

i am trying to plot a graph for the same 2 columns and i used this code -

**`plt.figure(figsize = (3,3))`
`df["gender", "heart_disease"].plot(kind = "bar")`
`plt.xlabel("heart_disease")`
`plt.ylabel("gender");`**

[this is the image after running the code from my previous question here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTz48.png)
This is Throwing an error, what is the right code for this?

Comment: _This is Throwing an error_ Don't make us guess what the error is...